# How do I know whether to use Python 2 or Python 3?

Tags: python

As we all know, usually Python projects exclusively run on the Python version (2 or 3) that they were made for.

However, when I come across Python projects, for example [this one](https://github.com/freshrichard/smartytotwig) on GitHub, they almost never state the necessary Python version.

How do you know which Python you need to run the project?

Comment: Assume Python 2.7. By FAR the most widely used version.

Comment: The only foolproof way I know of is to run the project in both Python 2/3 and see if one fails. Some projects *could* work in both.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't support a means to determine this automatically.

You (the author of a python project) can make your python application friendly, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224736/how-to-write-python-code-that-is-able-to-properly-require-a-minimal-python-versi).

However, if the author didn't do that (and most don't) then you can only try and hope for the best, AFAIK.