# Python: Sending the print function as a parameter

Tags: python

My professor had mentioned that it's possible to pass functions like print as a parameter, but when I try and actually implement it I get a syntax error. Is it something small that I am missing here?

```
 def goTime(sequence, action):
    for element in sequence:
       action(element)

 def main():
    print("Testing Begins")
    test = list ( range( 0 , 20, 2) ) 
    goTime(test, print)
    print("Testing Complete")
```

Upon running the following, I receive this syntax error:

```
goTime(test, print)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I define my own function that uses print, it works, like so:

```
def printy(element):
   print(element)

def goTime(sequence, action):
   for element in sequence:
      action(element)

def main():
   print("Testing Begins")
   test = list ( range( 0 , 20, 2) ) 
   goTime(test, printy)
   print("Testing Complete")
```

Comment: which version of python?  `print` is only a function in 3.

Comment: @roippi you can also do `from __future__ import print_function` to get it in earlier versions.

Comment: Bah, I was using an older version. Stupid mistake, thanks guys.

Comment: Just a note: Python2.7 ain't just _an older version of python_. Is still heavily used :)

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3 that will work out of the box. In Python 2.7 however, you can do:

```
from __future__ import print_function
def foo(f,a):
    f(a)

foo(print,2)
2
```

Note that in Python2.7 after you do `from __future__ import print_function` you won't be able to use `print` like a keyword any more:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print 'hi'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print 'hi'
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Although I think your professor only wanted to make a point that functions in Python are *first class citizens* (ie: objects) and they can be passed around as any other variable. He used a controversial example though :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think you need the ticks around `print_function`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Lol, definitely not needed. Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass `print` in Python2, because it's a keyword rather than a function. It's possible in Python3.

You can try to import new print function from future. Check this question:

[How to gracefully deal with failed future feature (__future__) imports due to old interpreter version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388069/python-graceful-future-feature-future-import)

and then you can use it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sys.stdout`

```
import sys

def printy(element):
    sys.stdout.write(str(element)+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

In python2 You can wrap `print` inside of a wrapper function and pass that:

```
def PrintWrapper(arg):
    print(arg)

def MyFunc(x, func):
    func(x)

# call the function with the wrapper as an argument
MyFunc("Hello world", PrintWrapper)
```